# how to check password on aes256 archive without decrypting

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes

I have a 200GB encrypted file as aes256.
I believe the password is one of 10 however it takes 5+ hours to decrypt currently before it gives an archive failed message in terminal.

my command is:
openssl enc -in ~/path/file.tgz.aes256 -aes-256-cbc -d -k password | tar -zxv -C ~/Desktop/location/

Is there a command I can run to quickly test archive with different passwords to ascertain the right password to use (brute force, essentially, but with a library of 10 passwords).

Comment: Stackoverflow is for *programming* questions. Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: What format is the data, can you recognize if it is successfuly decrypted by looking at it?

Answer (score 2):

Decrypt the first part of the file data specifying no padding, it will need to be a multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES). Then check if the decryption succeeded by looking at the decrypted data. It will either be what looks like random bytes or the correct data.

But your decryption is very slow, I can decrypt 200MB/s on an iPhone so 200GB would only take about 15 minutes plus the time to read the 200GB from disk. You may need to find another implementation that takes advantage of the Intel AES instructions (AES-NI). Software only decryption can be up to 1000 times slower.

Comment: I think you meant to write 16-bytes for the AES block size?